# Regex for the following string I'd like to split: 1.5 cc or 1.5cc

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following sting input that I need to split apart for output.  Example **1.5 cc** or **1.5cc**
I am doing this right now based on the space separating the input string using the following code:

```
var immunization = msg['dose_size'].toString().trim();
immunization = immunization.split(' ');
var amount = immunization[0];
var unit = immunization[1];
```

In testing however, I came across the fact the input is not always formatted that way, sometimes the space is missing. so my output for the input with no space is 1.5cc and the second output is empty.

I tried using a regular expression like: \d*.?\d+ and that works, but since it finds a match on the 1.5 I get an empty value for the first output and the "cc" for the second output, I need both.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a near duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500482/regex-to-find-integers-and-decimals-in-string/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code grab the data:

```
/(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\s*(\S+)/.exec(inputString)
```

- `(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)` will match decimal number, where it will accept integer `34`, regular decimal numbers `34.555`, and also allow `.5555` and `4533.` to pass.
- Followed by `\s*` matching optional spaces.
- Followed by `(\S+)` matching and capturing the next token (without space character).

If there is match, it will return an array, where index 1 of the array is the decimal number, and index 2 of the array is the unit.

Comment: I appreciate the info.  I tried to code your suggestion, but get an error on the line 4.                                                                 var immunization = msg['dose_size'].toString().trim();
var re = new RegExp("/(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\s*(\S+)/", "g");
var immunizationArray = re.exec(immunization);
var amount = immunizationArray[0];
var unit = immunizationArray[1];

Comment: Can you show sample input? And if you want to use `RegExp` constructor, you have to remove the starting and ending `/`, and escape all the backslashes \. Or you can just take the part before `exec`, which is literal RegExp, and assign to `re`.

Comment: I don't have a sample file if that's what you mean, but examples of what I'm trying to parse would be var immunization = "1.5 cc"; or "1.5cc" or .5mL for example

Comment: The regexp could be simpler: dose.match(/(\d*\.?\d*)\s?(\w+)/);

Comment: @TorstenWalter: How strict you want the regex to be depends on the data. If you see the my answer to the [near duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500482/regex-to-find-integers-and-decimals-in-string/), you will see an even simpler regex.

Comment: Of course, one could be as dense or elaborate as needed. I was referring to the specific requirements. Dealing with lookaheads and conditionals seems like a slight overhead and makes reading the regex harder in my opinion.

Comment: @TorstenWalter: There is no lookahead and conditional here. Only `OR`.

Comment: @nhahtdh I stand corrected. There's just a silent group - I always mix up the colon and the equals sign here.